# Remotely CD to current logged in user

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I currently have a script that uses the following to run the main batch file using a remote CMD application:

```
cd c:/remoteinstallers & ME_Unavailable_Fix
```

However when running this remotely it will default to my own user profile as the first line of the batch file contains:

```
cd/D "%UserProfile%"
```

Is there any way to cd to the current logged in user and then continue the rest of the script from there instead of it automatically looking for my own profile?

I have tried using the following but do not know if it would be possible to store the UserName variable and then CD to them from here

```
WMIC /node:"computername/IPAddress" COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME
```

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to get this working with the following:

```
@Echo Off
cd /D c:\users
:GetInput
Set "UserProfile="
Rem Request input from the user.
Set /P "UserProfile=Please enter the location of your UserProfile directory: "
If Not Defined UserProfile GoTo GetInput
If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\" GoTo GetInput
Rem Make the UserProfile directory the current directory
CD /D "%UserProfile%"
Echo Your current directory is %CD%
```